# Не передаётся & в POST

Tags: post, ajax, javascript

Не передаётся & в POST
..........

```
aParams['idns'] = idnsg;
aParams['adds'] = adds;
//aParams = "idns="+idnsg+"&adds="+adds;
if(document.ffedit.msgo.value)
{
var bufmsgo = document.ffedit.msgo.value;
//bufmsgo.replace('&','%26');
//bufmsgo=bufmsgo.replace('&','%26');
//bufmsgo=bufmsgo.utf8_encode(bufmsgo);
//aParams+="&msgo="+encodeURIComponent(bufmsgo);
aParams['msgo'] = encodeURIComponent(bufmsgo);
//aParams['msgo'] = bufmsgo;
}
else
//aParams+="&msgo=0";
aParams['msgo'] = 0;
ajax.open("POST", page, true);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;');
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-length', aParams.length);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Connection','close');
ajax.send(aParams);
```

.......
Какие будут предложения?

Есть предположения, что проблема в кодировках сайт работает на windows-1251.

---

Как и советовали: "По идее encodeURIComponent должно хватать", encodeURIComponent, действительно, хватает. Просто у меня скрипт в браузере закешировался, и браузер не реагировал на изменения в коде.
Спасибо всем кто откликнулся на мою просьбу о помощи.
Выложу рабочий вариант:

```
adds=0;
if(document.ffedit.adds.value==1)
if(document.ffedit.adds.checked)
adds=1;
aParams = "idns="+idnsg+"&adds="+adds;
if(document.ffedit.msgo.value)
aParams+="&msgo="+encodeURIComponent(document.ffedit.msgo.value);
else
aParams+="&msgo=0";
ajax.open("POST", page, true);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;');
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-length', aParams.length);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Connection','close');
ajax.send(aParams);

};
```

Comment: По идее encodeURIComponent должно хватать

Comment: Почему то не хватает. Этот код часть ajax запроса, который отправляется к php  скрипту и туда уже приходят переменые idns, adds,
msgo, но если в msgo есть &, то на нём идёт обрыв строки. Например, если в msgo='тес&т', то придёт 'тес'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположение верное, [читаем](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/webdev/17640/).

Совет там, в принципе, есть (iconv), от меня совет, пока (если) не поздно, перейти на utf-8, сбережете много нервов.

Comment: Спасибо за статью, я её, кстати, раньше читал, когда были проблемы с восприятием php того, что ajax передаёт и функцию iconv я использую. Но на encodeURIComponent я не обратил особого внимания, так как такой проблемы на тот момент предо мной не стояло.
Ещё бы научили правильно код вставлять в вопросы :-)

Comment: В редакторе каждый блок отделяется двумя пробелами, конкретно код - либо 4 пробела переда каждой строкой, либо выделить и нажать кнопку такую:

101

010

А еще см [тут](http://hashcode.ru/markdown_help/)